# How to read Golden Gate's trail files using Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: pentaho, kettle, oracle-golden-gate

I am trying to read Golden Gate's trail file using Pentaho Data Integration (KETTLE), but I don't know how to do this? Anyone please help me how to read the Golden Gate's trail file.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Senthil.

Answer (score 1):

A Golden Gate trail has a non-trivial structure:

https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWUAD/wu_fileformats.htm

It should be possible to parse this with PDI, but such a solution will be quite complicated. Here are some possible approaches:

1) Try to split the file into its various "areas", and process the areas one by one, possibly with sub-transformations to keep it modular and organized.

2) If you are looking for text within the file(s), you might be able to use the "Load text from file" plugin in the PDI Marketplace. It uses [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) to attempt to extract text from documents.

3) If you are willing to write code to do this, it would make a great plugin for PDI :)  When I encounter complex file structures, I usually write an [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) grammar to do the parsing, then I write a PDI plugin to call the parser and transform the values into a PDI row (i.e. tabular) format.